# как понимать двойной щелчок по файлу

Tags: python, python-3.x

можете объяснить или показать куда копать? Есть файл с кодом например

```
def start():
    c = a + b
    print(c)
```

сохраняем его и если щёлкнуть по нему два раза(запустить) то выскочит cmd и закроется, правильно ли понимаю что запуск модуля из шелл не совсем правильно? Что надо сделать для "правильного" запуска созданного модуля?

Comment: Тут просто объявлена функция, но нет ее вызова. Кроме того, для того чтобы не было закрытия файла добавьте хотя бы `input()`, тогда будет ожидание на ввод чего-либо и консоль не закроется

Comment: Скрипт открылся, выполнил свою работу и закрылся. Всё абсолютно правильно

Comment: вообще то по файлу кликать нельзя, можно кликать по иконке :) Вы кликаете по иконке определяется расширение файла, и запускается соответствующая команда связанная с расширением файла. В данном случае запускается интерпретатор Python и ему на вход подается указанный вами файл. После окончания обработки программа завершается.